# Don't Understand Error Message on Git Bash On Windows 10 After Trying to Update It

Tags: windows-10, bash, git, updates

I was trying to update my git bash on a windows 10 using command `git update-git-for-windows`. I am new to this and still learning so I don't understand the error message it showed on the terminal.

[image]

Comment: You need to add the certificate being used for the secure connection to your certificate store.  The certificate in question is self-signed, and by default, unless the end user trusts a self-signed certificate, it cannot be used to make secure connections.  The website in the message has all the instructions you need to resolve this problem.  This is a curl problem, specifically curl is attempting to use a self-signed certificate, you would get this error with any secured download with curl.

Comment: I still don't understand the certificate thing. Is there anything I should look up so I at least get the concept and understand a bit more -- at least enough to deal with this problem.

Comment: I am working on an answer, but it basically boils down to the fact, CURL is attempting to use a certificate and the OS doesn't trust it.  This means the certificate cannot be used.  You can either just download the current version of GIT and replace your current installation, or trust the certificate, and update the installation through the command you used.

Comment: Is this a company machine?  If it is then this is a problem only your IT Administrator can solve.

Comment: Meta: Please don't post screenshots for text errors. They aren't searchable. Copy & paste that error into a code box.

Comment: The URL it's trying to access is somewhere under `https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/` which is definitely served with a good certificate.